# Using Airtable to fetch data from my English quiz project (iOS-swift)

Tags: ios, swift, api, request, airtable

I'm new to iOS, self-learning swift, currently on API section and want to use Airtable for my English quiz project, I have figured out how to fetch data and show questions/options,

```
@objc func fetchQandA() {
    let urlStr = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appCwgj8Lq47t3SAT/QandA?maxRecords=10&view=Grid%20view"
    let apiKey = "apiKey"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("Bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let qAndA = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.numberOfQuestion.text = "Question \(self.questionIndex+1)"
                self.questionLabel.text = qAndA.records[self.questionIndex].fields.question
                self.optionA.setTitle(qAndA.records[self.questionIndex].fields.optionA, for: .normal)
                self.optionB.setTitle(qAndA.records[self.questionIndex].fields.optionB, for: .normal)
                self.optionC.setTitle(qAndA.records[self.questionIndex].fields.optionC, for: .normal)
                self.optionD.setTitle(qAndA.records[self.questionIndex].fields.optionD, for: .normal)
            }
            self.optionA.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.01954602264, green: 0.266705811, blue: 0.2860710323, alpha: 1)
            self.optionB.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.01954602264, green: 0.266705811, blue: 0.2860710323, alpha: 1)
            self.optionC.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.01954602264, green: 0.266705811, blue: 0.2860710323, alpha: 1)
            self.optionD.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.01954602264, green: 0.266705811, blue: 0.2860710323, alpha: 1)
            print(qAndA.records[self.questionIndex].fields.question)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
    
}
```

but when it comes to checking answer, I got stuck...

```
func checkAnswer(userAnswer: String) -> Bool {
    if userAnswer == response.records[self.questionIndex].fields.answer {
        scoreNumber += 1
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This will get a fatal error since response(struct that I made for the API) is found nil, I know maybe I need to request again to fetch answer and match with user input, but I can't figure out how to check my answer...

```
func checkAnswer(userAnswer: String) -> Bool {
    let urlStr = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appCwgj8Lq47t3SAT/QandA?maxRecords=10&view=Grid%20view"
    let apiKey = "apiKey"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("Bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let data = data,
           let answer = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data) {
            if userAnswer == answer.records[questionIndex].fields.answer {
                scoreNumber += 1
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try not to share your API keys publicly. Maybe edit it out now.

Comment: @gduverger gotcha! thanks for reminding.